# Unknown discoloration on tomato plant: how serious is this?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, tomatoes

One of the tomato plants in our garden has discoloration both on the upper leaves and on one or two of the fruit, as here:

[image]

[image]

How serious is this, and how should I address it? Is the plant salvageable? Do I need to worry about the rest of the tomato plants?